# I want to add a page in printpreviewdialog every time my for next loop ends its iteration in getting the image of my panel

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel which has a layout and I want to take it to printdialog and add a page to it every time my for next loop ends and changes the layout of the panel, so I could print all the pages that the For loop has gathered and print them all at once. 
My code is like this:

```
Private bmp As Bitmap
Private Sub PrintDTRToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles PrintDTRToolStripMenuItem.Click

 PrintDocument1.Print()

 End Sub

 Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
  For Each line In Me.TextBox1.Lines
'(Inside this are codes in passing data to my panel, I cant paste it here because it is too long)

'And this right here is my print code

 bmp = New Bitmap(Panel1.DisplayRectangle.Width, Panel1.DisplayRectangle.Height)
        Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
        Dim Hdc As IntPtr = G.GetHdc()
        SendMessage(Panel1.Handle, WM_PRINT, Hdc, DrawingOptions.PRF_OWNED Or DrawingOptions.PRF_CHILDREN Or DrawingOptions.PRF_CLIENT Or DrawingOptions.PRF_NONCLIENT)
        G.ReleaseHdc(Hdc)
        G.Dispose()
        PrintPreviewDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        e.HasMorePages = True
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)


        e.HasMorePages = True

    Next

    Dim startIndex = currentItemIndex
    Dim endIndex = Math.Min(currentItemIndex + itemsPerPage - 1, TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1)

    'There are more pages to print if there are more items to print.
    e.HasMorePages = currentItemIndex < TextBox1.Lines.Count

 End sub


Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
    currentItemIndex = 0
End Sub
```

What it does is it skips the other records or lines of my for next loop and only prints the last line of my textbox.

Comment: You should learn how printing works in WinForms.  Showing the preview dialogue inside the loop doesn't make sense.  You handle the `PrintPage` event of the `PrintDocument` and you set `e.HasMorePages` to `True` for all but the last page.  If you want to print 10 pages then the `PrintPage` event needs to be raised 10 times, once per page.  That's why it's named `PrintPage`.

Comment: By the way, replace `Me.TextBox4.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine)` with `Me.TextBox4.Lines`.

Comment: Learn about printing here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?548579. There are more threads on printing by the same user in the same forum.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I really appreciate your advice and help sir. You see this is my first time making an app with printing, could you tell me what you meant about this "If you want to print 10 pages then the PrintPage event needs to be raised 10 times, once per page."? And I dont really know how to do this hehehe

Comment: No, you don't really know how to do that, which is why I provided a link to a tutorial on printing: so you could learn.

Comment: Okay sir, I read the tutorial you sent to me but could you tell me what you meant by this "If you want to print 10 pages then the PrintPage event needs to be raised 10 times, once per page."?

Comment: For one thing, it should be self-evident. The `PrintPage` event prints a page. If you have multiple pages to print, you need multiple events.  Secondly, printing multiple pages is referenced in both of the first two posts in that tutorial thread so I'm afraid that I don't believe you when you say that you have read it.  I'm done here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so where do I put my next page code? In my button or in the printpage? Because I'm confused with it, because I'm using a for next loop.

Comment: Try reading the tutorial again, properly this time. The answer to that question is explained in the first post, under the "PrintPage" heading. The ONLY thing you should be doing in the `Click` event of your `Button` is calling `Print` on the `PrintDocument`. That tutorial clearly explains that all initialisation (e.g. resetting a page number to 0) is done in the `BeginPrint` event handler and all the the actual printing is done in the `PrintPage` event handler. If you're not doing that then you're doing it wrong, so start again and do it as instructed.

Comment: sir @jmcilhinney my code inside print_page is :

    'e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)'

Now when I transfered my data passing code into print_page, 'e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0)' gives the error 

Value cannot be null,
Parameter name: image

What do I do with it?

Comment: If you want to draw the `Image` that is assigned a variable then obviously you have to assign an `Image` to that variable. If you're getting an error message telling that that argument is null then obviously you haven't done that. The rules of how variables work don't change just because you're doing some printing. You can use the value of a variable in any way - printing or otherwise - if that variable has no value. Don't ignore what you already know because you're learning something new.

Comment: Thanks for the advice sir, but now it only prints the last line of my textbox, it skips the other records or lines of my for next loop

Comment: If it doesn't work then you did it wrong. We can't tell you what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did. Please consider whether you current issue is really part of this question or is actually a new question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney my code is at the bottom of this page sir.

Comment: If you have more information to add then add it to the question.  Don't create an answer that doesn't contain an answer to the question.  I would have posted a comment myself except that long code snippets are all but unreadable in comments.  You don't have that problem because you can edit your question to add code or any other relevant information.

Comment: I changed my question sir @jmcilhinney.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a self-contained answer to the question as asked but I wanted to post a fairly long example so a comment was not appropriate.  The following code demonstrates how to print multiple pages.  If you create a form with a `Button`, `PrintDocument` and `PrintPreviewDialog` and set the `Document` property of the dialogue, you can run this code and see it in action.  Set a breakpoint and step through the `PrintPage` event handler to see how the current item to be printed is tracked across pages.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

    Private items As List(Of String) 'Store data to be printed here.
    Private itemsPerPage As Integer
    Private currentItemIndex As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        items = New List(Of String) From {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten"}
        itemsPerPage = 3
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Start printing.
        'PrintDocument1.Print()
        PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_BeginPrint(sender As Object, e As PrintEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.BeginPrint
        'Start printing from the first item.
        currentItemIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        'Start printing the current page from the current item.
        Dim startIndex = currentItemIndex

        'Stop printing the current page after one page's worth of items or at the last item.
        Dim endIndex = Math.Min(currentItemIndex + itemsPerPage - 1, items.Count - 1)

        'Start printing the current page 10 pixels from the top.
        Dim yOffset = 10

        For currentItemIndex = startIndex To endIndex
            'Print the current item.
            e.Graphics.DrawString(items(currentItemIndex), Me.Font, Brushes.Black, 10, yOffset)

            'Print the next item 25 pixels lower.
            yOffset += 25
        Next

        'There are more pages to print if there are more items to print.
        e.HasMorePages = currentItemIndex < items.Count
    End Sub

End Class
```